# RegExp to search text inside HTML tags

Tags: html, regex, search

I'm having some difficulty using a RegExp to search for text between HTML tags. This is for a search function to search text on a HTML page without find the characters as a match in the tags or attributes of the HTML. When a match has been found I surround it with a div and assign it a highlight class to highlight the search words in the HTML page. If the RegExp also matches on tags or attributes the HTML code is becoming corrupt.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<html>
<span>assigned</span>
<span>Assigned > to</span>

<span>assigned > to</span>

<div>ticket assigned to</div>

<div id="assigned" class="assignedClass">Ticket being assigned to</div>

</html>
```

and the current RegExp I've come up with is:

(?<=(>))assigned(?!\<)(?!>)/gi

which matches if assigned or Assigned is the start of text in a tag, but not on the others. It does a good job of ignoring the attributes and tags but it is not working well if the text does not start with the search string.

Can anyone help me out here? I've been working on this for a an hour now but can' find a solution (RegExp noob here..)

## UPDATE 2

https://regex101.com/r/ZwXr4Y/1 show the remaining problem regarding HTML entities and HTML comments.

When searching the problem left is that `&nbsp;` is not ignored, all text inside HTML entities and comments should be ignored. So when searching for "b" it should not match `&nbsp;` even if the HTML entity is correctly between HTML tags.

Comment: Search for text between `>` and the next `<` - something like this: `/>([\w> ]+?)</g`.  [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yI6yZ0/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update #2**

Regex:

```
(<)(script[^>]*>[^<]*(?:<(?!\/script>)[^<]*)*<\/script>|\/?\b[^<>]+>|!(?:--\s*(?:(?:\[if\s*!IE]>\s*-->)?[^-]*(?:-(?!->)-*[^-]*)*)--|\[CDATA[^\]]*(?:](?!]>)[^\]]*)*]])>)|(e)
```

Usage:

```
html.replace(/.../g, function(match, p1, p2, p3) {
    return p3 ? "<div class=\"highlight\">" + p3 + "</div>" : match;
})
```

[**Live demo**](https://regex101.com/r/aH7dD3/4)

Explanation:

As you went through more different situations I had to modify RegEx to cover more possible cases. But now I came with this one that covers almost all cases. How it works:

- Captures all `<script>` tags and their contents
- Captures all `CDATA`blocks
- Captures all HTML tags (opening / closing)
- Captures all HTML comments (as well as IE if conditional statements)
- Captures all *targeted* strings defined in last group inside remaining text (here it is
  `(e)`)

Doing so lets us quickly manipulate our target. E.g. Wrap it in tags as represented in usage section. Talking performance-wise, I tried to write it in a way to perform well.

This RegEx doesn't provide a 100% guarantee to match correct positions (99% does) but it should give expected results most of the time and can get modified later easily.

Comment: This works much better, thanks! But if you search for "s" now it is marked twice because assigned has 2 of them. So ss is highlighted. Is it possible to stop after the first match? So only "s" is matched (but matched for each instance in the HTML, not only once)?

Comment: When you search for `s` so surely you mean all `s` letters. Why should you highlight only one `s` of a row of `s` letters?

Comment: I'm sorry! You are absolutely right. One more issue though is that the text can also not be inside CDATA tags, //<![CDATA[ and //]]> because then my alteration of the text breaks the script. Can you help me on this?

Comment: Between script tags might be a better check also

Comment: <script>function assigned_to()</script> can not be included, same goes for CDATA tags, because a search starts with one character and then I have problems

Comment: <html>
<span>assigned</span> ==> should be found
<span>Assigned > to</span> ==> should be found
<![CDATA[
<script>function assigned_to()</script>  ==> should be ignored
]]>
//<![CDATA[
<script>function assigned_to()</script>  ==> should be ignored
]]>//
<span>assigned > to</span>  ==> should be found

<div>ticket assigned to</div>  ==> should be found

<div id="assigned" class="assignedClass">Ticket being assigned to</div>  ==> should be found

</html>

Comment: Try [**`s(?![^<>]*(([\w\/"']|]])>|<\/script>))`**](https://regex101.com/r/vP6mH1/1)

Comment: That works with s but if you use e(?![^<>]*(([\w\/"']|]])>|<\/script>)) it will match the e in <title>car</title>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124029/discussion-between-frederic-cox-and-revo).

Comment: l've made an example where you can see the part inside script/cdata is still recognized regex101.com/r/jI9zP0/1
so the script is changed and breaks my HTML page after searching. I think you are nearly there .. (and would like to thank you for your efforts so far, this regexp stuff is pretty complex!)

Comment: There are many cases which should be taken into consideration and I tried to provide a better solution on this problem. Please check update #2.

Comment: I found a way to get it working using (?![^<>]*(([\/\"']|]]|\b)>)) preceeded with my search string. One problem left though it the HTML entities, how do we ignore them in this regular expression? I found it is &[^\s]*; but I'm not sure where it fits in the (?![^<>]*(([\/\"']|]]|\b)>)) so that if I search "n" it does not match to &nbsp; for example

Comment: How did you find it a working solution while it doesn't match expected string?

Comment: It was working fine for the initial requirement (searching between HTML tags). I just didn't take HTML entities into account, which is now a problem :)

Comment: Can you help me on this? I've tried but I can't get it to work inside of (?![^<>]*(([\/\"']|]]|\b)>)) , &[^\s]*; should fit in somewhere without breaking the existing results

Comment: Would you please add it with enough information to your post? Sorry it's not clear for me right now.

Comment: Sure I have added an "update 2" in my post. Kindly check I hope it is clear now

Comment: You could add `(&[#\w]+;)` within a side of alternation. Preferably one before search term `(e)`.

Comment: ((&[#\w]+;))b(?![^<>]*(([\/\"']|]]|\b)>)) does not work

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/ZwXr4Y/4 is working fine. I found a solution it seems :-) Thanks for your help

Comment: It catches "I would like food for >5 people" and also twitter handles e.g. @matthewtbaker btw.

Answer (score -1):

try this

[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mV4yH4/1)

```
string.match(/<.{1,15}>(.*?)<\/.{1,15}>/g)
```

this means <.{1,15}>(.*?)</.{1,15}> that anything that between html tag

```
 <any> Content </any>
```

will be the target or the result for example

```
 <div> this is the content </content>
```

"this is the content" this is the result